# Use a scanner to read integer values from user input

Tags: java

So far I have this code below:

```
    class Card{

    private static String[] pairArray{"A,A","K,K","Q,Q","J,J","10,10",
                     "9,9","8,8","7,7","6,6","5,5","4,4","3,3","2,2"};

    public static void generateRandom(){
    int minimum = 0;
    int maximum = 13;
    int randomNum = minimum + (int)(Math.random()* maximum);


       System.out.print("Player 1, You have been dealt a pair of: ");
       System.out.println(pairArray[randomNum]);

   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateRandom();
    }
  }
```

It randomly assigns an element from the array to player 1.

I need to read a users input of how many players he wants to play with, then produce this 4 times with each player getting a different set of cards. I think I need to use the scanner feature, but I'm unsure of where to include it in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = s.nextInt();
```

That'll read the int the user inputs. And you put that before generateRandom(); in your main. Using the number the user gives, you can do whatever you want with it, including making a while loop that makes that many random stuff. You don't provide much info, so this is as much as I can give.